# Comparing 2 data frames and writing the result to a 3rd

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames with identical dimensions A,B.  First column of each data frame is a date.  I would like to create a 3rd data frame that has 0s where A < B and 1s where A > B where the comparison is done element wise excluding the date column.  This is what I have done so far which works without looping.

```
C = A
C[] = 0
temp = unlist(as.relistable(as.matrix(C[-1])))
temp[which(A[-1]>B[-1])] = 1
C = data.frame(C[1], relist(temp))
```

But it seems like there has to be an easier way to do this (especially given the data.frame dimensions are identical).

Generically, what is the proper method of comparing 2 data frames element wise and writing the result to a 3rd data frame?

Comment: What about when `A == B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRUE` and `FALSE` are `1` and `0` repsectively so you should just be able to do this...

```
C <- ( A > B ) + 0
```

To exclude the first column just use `[` to subset it like this:

```
C <- ( A[,-1] > B[,-1] ) + 0
```

And by way of example:

```
A <- data.frame( Date1 = as.POSIXct( Sys.Date()+101:105 ) , Date2 = as.POSIXct( Sys.Date()-1001:1005 ) )
#       Date1      Date2
#1 2013-12-13 2010-12-07
#2 2013-12-14 2010-12-06
#3 2013-12-15 2010-12-05
#4 2013-12-16 2010-12-04
#5 2013-12-17 2010-12-03

B <- data.frame( Date1 = as.POSIXct( Sys.Date()+106:110 ) , Date2 = as.POSIXct( Sys.Date()-1006:1010 ) )
#       Date1      Date2
#1 2013-12-18 2010-12-02
#2 2013-12-19 2010-12-01
#3 2013-12-20 2010-11-30
#4 2013-12-21 2010-11-29
#5 2013-12-22 2010-11-28

C <- ( A > B ) + 0

#     Date1 Date2
#[1,]     0     1
#[2,]     0     1
#[3,]     0     1
#[4,]     0     1
#[5,]     0     1
```

Comment: The `+ 0` merely casts the result as an integer. Without, the elements of `C` is just `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: @MrGumble what is your point? I *want* to cast to `1` and `0` to make it explicit. And you can't do `C <- as.integer( ( A[,] > B[,] ) ` and retain the `data.frame` strucutre (`as.integer` will coerce to a vector).

Comment: Thank you very much a lot for your response.  It is a lot simpler than I expected.  As a follow up, is there a generic way to get the indices of the matrix where A>B?  For example if I have a matrix C and I want to square all the values in C where A>B.  Is the best way to manipulate the matrix of 1s and 0s to accomplish what I want?

Comment: @hjw I'd do `C * C ^ ( A > B )` to give you `C*(C^1) = C^2` or `C*(C^0)=C`

Comment: @SimonO101 I just pointed out the `+ 0`. You have a very neat and concise answer.

Comment: @MrGumble ah ok, I thought you meant that it was a *bad* thing to do! Thanks!